# Solve $x^2 -3x+2 \equiv 0 \pmod 6$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, polynomial-congruences

I need help understading how to solve this equation. 
$x^2-3x+2 \equiv 0 \pmod 6 $

I'm having trouble with the said equation.

Comment: The ring of integers mod 6 has (2)(3) as zero divisors.  When $x \equiv 4 \pmod 6$ Then $(x-1)(x-2) = (3)(2)\equiv 0 \pmod 6.$  And what about $x \equiv -1$?

Comment: Your universe has six elements. Trying them out in sequence is a logically valid (and fast) method for finding all the solutions. Don't do this when your universe is infinite though (as is the case with school level systems of numbers)! You will never complete the task in that case!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First notice that $x^2-3x+2=(x-1)(x-2)$

So we want any $x$ where any of the following are met:
$$x\equiv 1 \pmod 6$$
$$x\equiv 2\pmod 6$$
$$x \equiv 1\pmod 2\text{ and } x\equiv 2\pmod 3$$
$$x \equiv 0\pmod 2\text{ and } x\equiv 1\pmod 3$$

See if you can deduce when these are.

Comment: ^Note that $x\equiv2 \pmod 2$ is the same as $x\equiv 0 \pmod 2$, in case the $0$ confuses you.

Comment: x1=1+6m, x2=2+6m, x3=5+6m, x4=4+6m

Comment: @HarrysKavan Absolutely.

Comment: You could even summarise this as any $x\not\equiv 0\pmod 3$